# Using Play Framework Anorm, how do I get the auto-generated id back for an insert?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, anorm

Suppose I have:

```
case class SomeModel(
  id : Pk[Long],
  description : String
)

object SomeModel extends Magic[SomeModel] {
  def ayDogAy = {
    var aydog = SomeModel(NotAssigned, "aydog")
    this.insert(aydog)
  }
}
```

How do I get back the inserted id of aydog?

If it matters, my backing database is Postgres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Play 2 if you have an autoincrement long PK:

```
val id: Long = SQL("insert into bla bla bla").on("bleh", "blah").executeInsert().get
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use the Magic trait (as it is removed in Play 2.0), so I'm not sure if this works here too. In SQL you can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get the last id used on the connection. So you can do somehing like

```
    val id = SQL("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()")().collect {
               case Row(id: Int) => id
             }.head
    new SomeModel(new Id(id), "aydog")
```

I'm just playing around with Play right now. So this is nothing I'd recommend using in production without further investigations. I'm especially unsure if there might be concurrency issues, when several threads use the ayDogAy method.